# frontend is working but wp-admin not working

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello I have website that working well in my hostgator cpanel testing server and I have just switched  website to client server. I found that backend(wp-admin showing me The connection was reset in the firefox) isnt working right now and frontend working well.

I did lots of r & d like disable the all plugins and disable current activated theme in ftp but not a success.

Please help me guys.

Comment: What error you getting ? Can you define *Not working* ?

Comment: Define your url and which error find there

Comment: when I tried to access wp-admin. it showing me The connection was reset in firefox

Comment: http://electrician--melbourne.com.au

Answer (score 1):

please check your wp database in wp_options table

siteurl and home with bellow query :

SELECT * 
FROM  `wp_options` 
WHERE  `option_name` 
IN (
'siteurl',  'home'
);

and check option_value is coming correct?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your wp_config.php contains the correct new paths.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your old URL with your New URL for all the posts,pages,etc.

You can change the url by using following plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/

Comment: I changed the old server to new server. old server is expired.

Comment: The main problem what i thought is the new url was not updating proper in database.so that the wp-admin was not available for you. Do one thing,open database and go through your table. if you find any old server url in table then simply replace old url with the new url.
url is your server path(www.example.com)

for example:
old url --  www.oldexample.com
change to
new url -- www.newexample.com

Comment: Check wp-admin folder is avialable or not

Answer (score 0):

Open your exported sql file. and try to search and replace old domain name (may be with folder path) with the current domain name.

Comment: search your new database if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

Change the site url and home url in wp_options table.

Also check the rewrite base in your htaccess file.